# Poor FPS with mac webcam when used on Ubuntu on VMWare Fusion

Tags: video, mac, webcam

I have Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS running on VMWare Fusion Pro (v11.0.2) on MAC (Mojave 10.14.2). The VM has 2 processors and 4GB of RAM.

I am trying to connect to the camera on the on the MAC. I add the camera device as the MAC's built-in camera and it adds fine. To test it I opened cheese to view the camera - the camera light goes on quickly but it takes a long time to get the video (about 25 seconds). The updates post that are also very very slow, one image in 25 seconds, or 0.04fps. This makes it unusable. Switching the camera to something else improves a little but never more than 0.25fps (1 image switch in 4 seconds).

Same configuration of MAC and VMWare Fusion, I have tried this with the guest OS being WinXP, Win10 and they all work fine at about 15fps (1 image in 0.25sec)

What is making the image capture sooooo slow on Ubuntu? Is there some setting I can change to make it faster?

Comment: Use Parallels Desktop, just checked, works fine

Answer (score 2):

VMWare confirmed that this is a bug in their latest version 11.x and will be fixed with the next release. Previous versions work fine and I tried that with VMWare v8.x and it worked just fine!!

Comment: Confirmed, downgraded virtual machine hardware version to 14, launched Fusion 10, fps 0.67 → 22. I thought that different kext versions might cause issues, but I just dragged-and-dropped `VMware Fusion.app` from the install `.dmg` and it worked, no reboot needed or anything.